# Port Availability Scanner, written in Java (9)

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, socket

For purpose of practice and experience, I was working on a "Port Availability Scanner" written in Java. So far it's working but it's really slow. Especially on relatively large quantities of ports (1000+).

It's quite faster scanning localhost then my external IP (If it actually scans externally correctly).

As an additional note for if it really matters:
I am using Java 9.

**Code:**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    private static final Test instance = new Test("157.97.56.42", 80, 443, 21, 22, 25, 8080);
    private static String ip;
    private int[] ports = new int[1_000_000];

    private Test(String ip, int start, int end) {
        Test.ip = ip;

        ports: {
            int c = 0;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                ports[c++] = i;
            }

            ports = Arrays.copyOfRange(ports, 0, c + 1);
        }
    }

    private Test(String ip, int... ports) {
        Test.ip = ip;
        this.ports = ports;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread thread = new Thread(instance::check);
        thread.start();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Took: " + (end - start) + "ms.");
    }

    public void check() {
        if(ports.length > 1) {
            for (int port : ports) {
                System.out.println("Available " + port + ": " + Test.isAvailable(port));
            }
        } else if(ports.length == 1) {
            System.out.println("Available " + ports[0] + ": " + Test.isAvailable(ports[0]));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isAvailable(int port) {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return true;
        } finally {
            if(socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please can you review my code, especially performance-wise?

**Edit:**
Would it be possible by using NIO or any other form of MultiThreading the sake of speed?

Comment: I forgot that was one of the rules here, thank you for reverting :)
I'll wait another day as you suggest to look at eventually other reviews.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why do you create a million element array? (`int[] ports = new int[1_000_000]`) It'd better to make it as large as the ports in constructor (`end-start` or `ports.length`)
2. Why all of this code?

   ```
   if(ports.length > 1) {
       for (int port : ports) {
           System.out.println("Available " + port + ": " + Test.isAvailable(port));
       }
   } else if(ports.length == 1) {
       System.out.println("Available " + ports[0] + ": " + Test.isAvailable(ports[0]));
   } else {
       throw new IllegalStateException();
   }
   ```

   You only really need

   ```
   for (int port : ports) {
       System.out.println("Available " + port + ": " + Test.isAvailable(port));
   }
   ```

   The result will be equivalent and the code is now more readable
3. Why did you make `ip` and `instance` static? Do you want to make the class a singleton?
4. The `ports` label is unnecessary in the first constructor
5. Use `InetAddress` instead of `String` for IPs' as from what I know `Socket`s convert the strings into `InetAdress`es anyway. It should somewhat improve performance (*change `ip` variable from `String` to `InetAddress` so you don't recreate the address on and on again*)
6. <s>Shouldn't this:</s>

   ```
   try {
       socket = new Socket(ip, port);
       return false;
   } catch (IOException e) {
       return true;
   } finally {
       if(socket != null) {
           try {
               socket.close();
           } catch (IOException ignored) { }
       }
   }
   ```

   <s>work the other way round? Why method `isAvailable` returns `true` when the 
   socket throws a exception? Looks like a bug to me</s> I misunderstood what you 
   meant by available. Your code is correct

Comment: I've changed my code to reflect your suggestions, but why I used `return false` when the Socket connected was because I thought, if it can connect something is using that port (A webserver for example) which would mean it's not available.

Comment: @Azoraqua I get it know. I misunderstood what you meant by available, sorry for that

Comment: Don't worry, thank you though. see the edit for additional question related to it, maybe you can answer it.

Comment: @Azoraqua I edited my answer a bit as you kind of misunderstood point 5 of my answer. Regarding the slower performance on external IP's, well that's no surprise. It's always slower to connect to some external IP than to connect to `localhost` straight away. There's not much you can do about it

Comment: I understand it, but could you explain to me, why connecting to my OVH machine is much faster then connecting to my own external IP (Almost 3 times faster)? And secondly, can you read my 2th edit about the changes related to code efficiency and such.

Comment: @Azoraqua it's hard to say as many factors may contribute to it but one of the options I see is that OVH has better internet speed than you've got. That's especially probable if you are close to OVH's server. Keep in mind I do not have as much knowledge regarding internet under-the-hood.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the feedback. 
I am happy with what I've got now.

Comment: @Azoraqua please don't change the code in your question after answers have been posted. I've reverted your changes.